# How to Start Any Fragment at the bigining by using ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

Hey i have 5 `Fragments`  like `Fragment1,Fragment2,Fragment3,`..Which i am Displaying in a `ViewPager` But I want `Fragment2` should display first instead of `Fragment1`when i am starting my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting the adapter for ViewPager, you can simply use [`setCurrentItem(position)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem%28int%29) to set the page selected at required position.

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
```

Comment: your answer is right According to my question .I am Posting a new Question have look at this.